# Can we Change the Value of ComponentsLocation from "Relative" to "HomeSite"?

Tags: windows, msbuild, wix, windows-installer

hii,
well i develop a setup.exe(bootstrapper) using GenerateBootstrapper.Bootstrapper to load my msi file after check and installing prerequisites.It perfectly running if i make **ComponentsLocation**

*)  either "**HomeSite**" to download prerequisites from the microsoft and install.

*) or "**Relative**" to take the prerequisites at the same location where my application exist and install.

But in my scenario i want that when i run setup.exe(bootstrapper) it first check component in the location where my application exist and IF it's(component) is not exist there then it download them from vendor's URL(Microsoft).
Is it possible with wix v3.5???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with the msbuild [GenerateBootstrapper task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164294.aspx).

As for the burn.exe tool in wix v3.5, it is still in development and currently undocumented. The wix.chm in the latest [weekly release](http://wix.sourceforge.net/releases/) does not yet mention burn.exe at the time of writing.

**edit**: The reason that it is not possible is that it is not really useful. I imagine you have two different deployement scenarios:

- the software is delivered
  on a CD or DVD with all the
  prerequisites included
- the software is
  downloaded as a zip archive and the prequisites are
  omitted to minimize download time

You need to prepare two different file trees anyway in this case. So just create a different bootstrapper for each scenario.

**edit2**: you can also create the two different bootstrappers, then create a third `setup.exe` which is a simple application that determines which of the two boostrappers to launch.

Comment: @ wcoenen ::
You are right.I can make different bootstrapper for each scenario.But Can't we make a single setup.exe file which check at the local repository and download also if not found any required component???
It will be useful and save our time and also increase the flexibility of the bootstrapper as it will download only those components which are not there with it,Not all of them..
As in my case i want the same it first checks for the components and if it find any error(like missing component,any file missing from components) then it will download that component.